# Iterate deeply nested object with unknown level and add remove key/value based on user provided conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could anyone please guide me how to achieve the below challenge which I am facing?

I have thousands of mock API request response JSON files. They are deeply nested, and they all are structured differently. I need to add/update/delete entry at the specfic location where the condition match which will be provided by user. I am not sure how to approach this problem? I have tried doing something like below. I am asking user for path for where to start looking. But this will increase time as user has to look for path in all file and pass that info to api. below code work upto 2 level only. need to search full tree where all user provides conditions matches, and at that place, I need to add/update/delete data. I took condition as an array of objects.

Draft Code

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const file = "./sample.json";
const actions = ["add", "delete", "update"];

const consumer = (file, key, where, data, action) => {
    try {
        const act = action.toLowerCase();
        if(!actions.includes(act) throw new Error("invalid action provided");
        if(_.isArray(where) && _.every(where, _.isObject())) throw new Error("no where clause condition provided");
        let content = require(file);
        let typeKeyContent = null;
        let keyContent = _.get(content, key);
        if(!keyContent) throw new Error("invalid key");
        
        if(_.isArray(keyContent)) {
            typeKeyContent = "array"
        } else if (_.isObject(keyContent)) {
            typeKeyContent = "object"
        }
        
        switch (act) {
            case "add":
                if (typeKeyContent === "array") {
                   // array logic
                   for (let i = 0; i < keyContent.length; i++) {
                       const result = where.every(element => {
                            for (let key in element) {
                                return keyContent[key] && element[key] === keyContent[key];
                            }
                       });
                        if (!result) {
                            console.log("attributes matching -> ", result);
                            return;
                        }
                        keyContent[i] = {...keyContent[i], ...data }
                   }
                   let newcontent = _.set(content, key, keyContent);
                    console.log("newcontent -> \n",JSON.stringify(newcontent, null, 2));
                   return;
                }
                const result = where.every(element => {
                    for (let key in element) {
                        return keyContent[key] && element[key] === keyContent[key];
                    }
                });
                if (!result) {
                    console.log("attributes matching -> ", result);
                    return;
                }
                
                keyContent = { ...keyContent, ...data };
                
                let newcontent = _.set(content, key, keyContent);
                console.log("newcontent -> \n",JSON.stringify(newcontent, null, 2));
                // TODO :: store back in json file
                break;
            default:
                console.log("reached default case");
                return;
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("ERROR :: CONSUMER ::", error);
    }
}
// AND based condition only
const conditions = [
    { name: "Essential Large" },
    { selected: true }
];
const newdata = { description: "our best service" } // wants to add new prop
consumer(file, "selected_items.essential", conditions, newdata, "add");
```

sample json

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "request": {},
  "response": {
    "ffs": false,
    "customer": {
      "customer_id": 1544248,
      "z_cx_id": 123456
    },
    "selected_items": {
      "essential": [
        {
          "id": 4122652,
          "name": "Essential Large",
          "selected": true,
          "description": "our best service" // will be added 

        },
        {
          "id": 4122653,
          "name": "Essential Large",
          "selected": true,
          "description": "our best service" // will be added 
        }
      ]
    },
    "service_partner": {
      "id": 3486,
      "name": "Some String",
      "street": "1234 King St."
    },
    "subject": "Project",
    "description": "Issue: (copy/paste service request details here Required"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that u are looking for a recursive function:

See this post as example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953697/iterating-through-array-of-nested-objects-with-javascript-lodash

Good luck!

Comment: so `key` is the keys to update, `where` is the condition `action` is what you need to do, `file` is what you want to update, and `data` is the future value or empty (in case of delete)? Just making sure I understand your problem. Can the condition occur multiple times?

Comment: file could be any mock json file. I just hardcoded for beginning purpose. I took key as a path which user is going to provide example selected_items.essential, this is going to increase user time. we can ignore key means we should search in whole json rather than asking user. rightly said, where is condition. data is future value and empty for deletion.

Comment: just to make sure, it's always JSON files right? I'm asking to wonder if they'd ever be `cyclic`

Comment: yes it would be json file only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to go through every key of a nested object right?

```js
function forEvery(object,fn){
  //obj is the object, fn is the function
  //this function should go through each item in an object loaded from JSON string
  //fn takes in 3 arguments: current element, that element's parent, level of depth(starts at 1)
    
  var arr=[]
  function recurse(obj,map,depth){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((a,i)=>{
      fn(obj[a],obj,a,depth) //because fn can affect the object so the if statement should after not before ;-;
      if(typeof obj[a]=="object"&&obj[a]!=null){ //if nested value is another object
        map.push(a); arr.push(map)
        recurse(obj[a],[...map],depth+1)
      }
    })
  }
  recurse(object,[],1)
}

//usage would be like:
//let customerCondition=/*some logic here*/
//let testObj=JSON.parse( (require('fs')).readFileSync('dirToSomeFile.json') )
forEvery(testObj,customerCondition)
```

Here's a live example

```js
let testObj={"status":200,"request":{},"response":{"ffs":false,"customer":{"customer_id":1544248,"z_cx_id":123456},"selected_items":{"essential":[{"id":4122652,"name":"Essential Large","selected":true},{"id":4122653,"name":"Essential Medium","selected":false}]},"service_partner":{"id":3486,"name":"Some String","street":"1234 King St."},"subject":"Project","description":"Issue: (copy/paste service request details here Required"}}
function forEvery(object,fn){
  //obj is the object, fn is the function
  //this function should go through each item in an object loaded from JSON string
  //fn takes in 3 arguments: current element, that element's parent, level of depth(starts at 1)
    
  var arr=[]
  function recurse(obj,map,depth){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((a,i)=>{
      fn(obj[a],obj,a,depth) //because fn can affect the object so the if statement should after not before ;-;
      if(typeof obj[a]=="object"&&obj[a]!=null){ //if nested value is another object
        map.push(a); arr.push(map)
        recurse(obj[a],[...map],depth+1)
      }
    })
  }
  recurse(object,[],1)
}

//example usage
let userQuery=[{ name: "Essential Large" },{ selected: true }]; //the user query in the format you gave
let userCondition={} //assuming each key across userQuery is unique, I set a model object for comparisons later on
userQuery.forEach(obj=>{ //I fill the model object :D
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>{
    userCondition[key]=obj[key]
  })
})
let testFn=(elem,parent,key,depth)=>{
  //I use comparisons with the model object
  let condition=typeof elem!="object"?false:
  Object.keys(userCondition)
  .every(item=>userCondition[item]==elem[item])
  //true if matches user condition(meaning elem must be an object), false otherwise
  if(condition){
    console.log(parent[key],"will now be deleted")
    delete(parent[key]) //deletion example(if user conditions match)
  }
}
forEvery(testObj,testFn)
console.log("and the changed object looks like",testObj)
```

[image: condition match]

[image]

Comment: thx, how can I apply my condition here? conditions = [{ name: "Essential Large" },{ selected: true }]; these condition can be present any where in a json file and could be repetitive. I have updated added comments in above in sample.json file.

Comment: const list = "Large";

let testFn = (depth, elem, parent, newdata) => {
    if (elem == list) {
      Object.assign(parent, newdata);
    }
};
I have modified it a bit. I tried with only one condition like above. Not sure how to tackle it with multiple condition as we can access only one value here.

Comment: you can make testFn any function you want.. process all kinds of things.. think of it like an `Array.forEach` but for *Objects*.. also it's `let testFn=(elem,parent,depth)=>{your code here}`

Comment: one edit: I give another argument called `key`, so there's the item, the parent, the key and the depth..<br>maybe you can have `let testFn = (depth, elem, childName, parent) => { if (childName ==  "Essential Large") { delete(parent[childName]) } };`<br>but I'm not sure how `[{ name: "Essential Large" },{ selected: true }]` is a condition and I just added that delete part because of the name of your question

Comment: thx, I got that part for key. however I am not sure how to handle combined key value in that level and add/remove on based on it.

Comment: ok.. without use of my answer.. in *words* pls explain an example of a condition for an item in an object to get deleted

Comment: let say if user provided us condition which could a single object in array or multiple. object would have single key value only. I took it as array of object but I am open for other solution. provided key value in this case example name with value essential large & selected with value true both should be present in json object at same level. only then I can perform add/remove/update operation. user can pass many such condition. I have added an image which might express my concern

Comment: sorry for the late response btw but I gave code to match your condition logic :D